# Is it possible to create a combination line and area chart in OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: openoffice-calc

Is there a way to create a graph that is a combination of lines and areas in OpenOffice Calc?

Currently the only way I know how is to make two charts, make the background of one transparent, and lay it on top of the other. But keeping them lined up spacially is a complete hassle and doesn't ever fully work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only combination available with LibreOffice or OpenOffice is the Line/Bar combination. An alternative would be to use [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) which is capable to combine different chart types, allowing for a line/area combination, too:

[image: gnumeric]